# Finding a splitting field for a semisimple algebra in GAP

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, gap

> Question: Given a semisimple finite dimensional algebra over the rationals in GAP.
> Is there a way to find a (minimal) splitting field of this algebra with GAP and an explicit Wedderburn decomposition?

The semisimple algebra is given as a subalgebra of the ring of $n  \times n$-matrices of the matrix algebra over the rationals. It is not a group algebra in general.

The GAP-command DirectSumDecomposition seems to give a decomposition of such an algebra into two-sided ideals (so a rough Wedderburn decomposition). I wonder whether there is a more detailed way to see what those two-sided ideals $L$ are exactly meaning to know $L \cong M_n(D)$ for $n$ a number and $D$ a division ring over the rationals.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Please, also, provide context with each question.

Comment: @Shaun I reduced it to one question. I think the question gives all details needed to answer it or what do you mean with context?

Comment: I mean that you need to explain what it is you know, how you would answer the question yourself, what motivated the question, *etc.* Consider answering the following (in an [edit]): What are you studying? What text is this drawn from, if any? If not, how did the question arise? What kind of approaches (to similar problems) are you familiar with? What kind of answer are you looking for? Basic approach, hint, explanation, something else? Is this question something you think you should be able to answer? Why or why not?

Comment: @Shaun Im a research mathematician and it is a fundamental problem in representation theory to find the Wedderburn decomposition of a semisimple algebra. The question basically asks for commands in GAP that might exist to answer this question (which I am not aware of, since sometimes it is hard to find the right commands/tricks in GAP even when they already exist). I added the reference tag.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you for the clarification

Comment: @Mare have you tried the [Wedderga package](https://gap-packages.github.io/wedderga/)?

Comment: @OlexandrKonovalov The description says it is for group algebras. Does it work for general semisimple algebras?

Comment: @Mare ah, I see - didn't read that carefully first time, sorry. No, it's for group algebras only.